# Painting in "Texture Paint" on a sculpture is leaving errors

Tags: texture-painting

[image: blender painting issue]

---

So i have sculpted half a horse & would like to learn how to paint it. I followed online blender painting manual & also have watched youtube tutorials.

So i used "smart UV project" to unwrap then i started painting in "texture paint". certain places over the sculpture leaves marks as shown (i have used the colour "white" only in the image above). Then i tried just UV unwrapping it from the "tools" when given the notices that i need UV unwrap & paint slot with the "!" by adding a paint slot. Both ways left me with the same result in different places. Also when using another colour somewhere else in certain places it turns those marks into that colour.

I have done some experimenting & also tried adjusting the angle limit in smart UV project & it changes the locations of where these occur. Also at the start of this occurring i went back into sculpture & tried smoothing out the horse more which did nothing at all to help the issue.

Can anyone please explain & tell me why i am getting this that i have never seen happen in tutorials after i have done the same thing with unwrapping & using brushes.

Comment: that marks are often caused by to small Island Margins. Try increasing that when you make your Smart UV Unwrap. For Texturepainting you can also try Lightmap Pack Unwrap or do it yourself with seams

Comment: I have tried increasing Island Margins in Smart UV Unwrap & Lightmap Pack Unwrap & i still get these marks appearing. As for doing it myself with seems, it is my understanding this does not work on sculpting mode objects & if it does it's somewhat problematic  compared to a object made in Edit Mode

Comment: I paint my objects that are sculpted all the time after retopologizing them to get workable density quads in my object. The unwrap itself has to be clean enough to work with, and there is a possibility with Smart Unwrap to get not only island margin errors, but also overlapping uv coordinates that cause problems.

Comment: Overlapping UV coordinates looks more like what it is seeing nothing changed really apart from location on object when i tried fixing island margins. I guess i will be needing to find a solution for overlapping UV coordinates. Thanks for the help

Comment: i looked into retopologizing & that looks like what i'l need to do. Thanks for all the help & this problem i hope should be prevented hopefully in future. All i can say about this is that it not as simple as it looks from watching & reading tutorials & seeing other peoples work go perfect with no marks or other problems. Honestly i thought it be simple as sculpt, unwrap, paint & done. I guess i was wrong in thinking things would be simple as explained & watched from a beginners & learners perspective with add-on's to help for making it easier & simpler

Comment: Retopoly did not work to fix this issue as i still got the marks. So right now i feel like my download of the free blender 2.79 is giving me what its worth & this has me wondering is there a better version where things work the way they should that i need to pay for